# Is there any better way to refer html elements by class names?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

Is there any other best practices to get a html element by class name?

```
let left = document.getElementsByClassName("pro-left");

for (let i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {

    left[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("Clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of for loop use a `forEach`

Comment: Better in what way? You want to make the code shorter or what is your goal?

Comment: What's wrong with `gEBCN`? It's the fastest possible, and you need it only once per document, since it returns a live collection. What would be even better than that ..? If you want to reduce code, use event delegation instead of individual event listeners.

Comment: @Esko I'm looking for somethin simple & short. The best way...

Comment: @Teemu Is it efficient?

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, it's the fastest possible, nothing beats `gEBCN` in performance, except `element.getElementsByClassName` in case you already have a reference to `element`.

Comment: @WenukaGTX: If you just don't like the hassle of typing the entire thing out, get an editor with auto-complete. The function does *exactly what it says on the tin* - if you think that isn't the most efficient option available, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I think getElementsByClassName is already a good best practice.
If you prefer a more modern approach you are probably looking for
the query selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

With this you can select elements like in css.

```
document.querySelector(".myclass")
```

The advantage is that you can select subclasses etc. very easily.

EDIT:

If you want to select multiple elements use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. but it gave me an error when I do this.|

let slider = document.querySelector("slider");
prev.addEventListener("click", function () {}

Comment: @WenukaGTX If you're looking for performance, `gEBCN` is about 100 times faster (this depends on the implementation) than `querySelectorAll`, which can be used outside the DOM too, e.g.. it finds elements from `documentFragment` and other parentless elements.

Comment: Whats the error? If you want to select multiple element you must use document.querySelectorAll.